# Redeploy Service Fabric application without version change

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've read about partial upgrade, but it always requires to change some parts of the packages application. I'd like to know if there's a way to redeploy a package without version change. In a way, similar to what VS is doing when deploying to the dev cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your local dev cluster, VS simply deletes the application before it starts the re-deployment. You could do the same in your production cluster, however this results in downtime since the application is not accessible during that time.

What's the reason why you wouldn't want to use the regular monitored upgrade? It has many advantages, like automatic rollbacks and so on.